# dynamic columns for dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Columns   [today],  [30days ago], [60days ago], [90 days ago]

I have a table the will provide me with the sales number fro today and 30days ago, 60 days ago and 90 days ago,

But the issue I have is to figure out what the actual date was 60 days ago.
I wanted to update my script not show me 60days ago but to show me the actual date 60days ago. I want to make my columns dynamic so i get the actual date 90days ago.

Can anyone help me here?

Please remember this is a long scripts and 10 columns and I want to change each column to show me the actual date and not the 90 days ago.

Comment: Use DATEADD. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Comment: How are you building the query right now?

Comment: What you need is a dynamic pivot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GETDATE()` and `DATEADD()` to get these values:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AS Today, 
       CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())) Minus30
```

Converting to `DATE` simply takes off the time portion.

Produces:

```
Today       Minus30
2015-06-08  2015-05-09
```

To use these values you can assign a few variables and set the values to be used later in your code:

```
DECLARE @today DATE, @Minus30 DATE

SELECT @today = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 
       @Minus30 = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE()))

PRINT @today
PRINT @Minus30
```

To use the values as column names, you'll need to use some dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @today NVARCHAR(15), @Minus30 NVARCHAR(15)

SELECT @today = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())), 
   @Minus30 = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())))


EXEC ('SELECT ''30'' AS ''' + @today + ''', ''123'' AS ''' + @Minus30 + '''')
```

Produces:

```
2015-06-08  2015-05-09
30          123
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to dynamically change the "Minus30" name.

Comment: I just need to dynamic way to reflecting today's day as the column's name.I am happy with the data inside the columns, But i want a dynamic column name that keep updating as when the data is refreshed.

Comment: @Afrah does the variable approach i just edited in allow you to do what you want? each time the statements are run they will be updated with latest values.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I was trying to show how the values could be retrieved, but have added a sample to set some variables that could be used later in code.

Comment: @Tanner - I think you didn't get what i am trying to do. I have column named today but i want this to be 08/06/2015 and when i refresh it tomorow i want to it to show me 09/06/2015 as a column name. also the column named [30 days ago] i want this to show as 09/05/2015 and not as [30 days ago]

Comment: @Afrah ok, it's not clear from your question. If you update it with some sample data and your desired output, i'll revisit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is best handled in the client code that retrieves the sql results. Using c# as an example:

```
string sql = String.Format(
    "SELECT [today] as [{0}], [30days ago] as [{1}], [60days ago] as [{2}], [90 days ago] as [{3}] FROM [MyTable]",
         DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString(),
         DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30).ToShortDateString(),
         DateTime.Today.AddDays(-60).ToShortDateString(),
         DateTime.Today.AddDays(-90).ToShortDateString());
```

If you really need to, you could put the same string logic into procedural sql, and save that to a stored procedure. But don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried doing this, but you can try to use an sp_rename statement using the variable names that @Tanner suggested:

```
DECLARE @Minus30 DATE

SELECT @Minus30 = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE()))
EXEC sp_rename 'Table.[30days ago]', @Minus30, 'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to build a list of dynamic date columns, you could do this using dynamic pivot method something like this:

**Creating a Test Table**

```
create table pvtTbl(DateColumns varchar(50),sales money,employeeid int);

insert into pvtTbl 
select cast(getdate() as date) datecol,1249.00 as sales,123 employeeid
UNION
select cast(dateadd(day,-30,getdate()) as date)  datecol,15615.00 as sales,456 employeeid
UNION
select cast(dateadd(day,-60,getdate()) as date) datecol,125583.00 sales,356 employeeid
UNION
select cast(dateadd(day,-90,getdate()) as date) datecol,25571.00 sales,859 employeeid
```

This part, I am just creating as an example to build the pivot table. But, you could actually create this step as an insert statement to a temp table in your stored proc, so that it will be updated each time to dynamically build your date columns using this query:

**Query to build a list of needed date values**

```
select cast(getdate() as date) datecol
UNION
select cast(dateadd(day,-30,getdate()) as date) datecol
UNION
select cast(dateadd(day,-60,getdate()) as date) datecol
UNION
select cast(dateadd(day,-90,getdate()) as date) datecol
```

After that, all you will need to do is build a dynamic pivot using `STUFF` function and `XML path` to first build a comma separated list of date values and then pivot it dynamically to output it as your columns like this:

**Dynamic Pivot to build date columns**

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.DateColumns)  
            FROM pvtTbl c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT  employeeid,' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select sales,employeeid,DateColumns
                from pvtTbl
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 sum(sales)
                for DateColumns in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

Anyway, this would be a good idea if you build this as a stored procedure. Let me know if you need any more help.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab8cf/5/0)